# Datepicker Date validation

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Is there a way to validate a date picked from Datepicker , if after selecting the date user removes half of it, for e.g date selected:20-Dec-2013, and user removes 2013 from the input box manually, and clicks on Save action.

Now when I am trying to debug and catch a custom parse exception on server side, the value I get from my bean is already null.

Can u give me some idea on how to parse this date on angular controller itself?

Comment: i use my datepicker with jquery validate, works like a charm, maybe you can try that

Comment: I am using angularjs.Sorry ,I missed it in my description.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a custom validation directive: <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfrw9/)</kbd>

Following directive takes the date string that was set in the input field. If your datepicker uses some other approach you have to change this directive a bit.

```
myApp.directive('isDate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            function validate(value) {

                var d = Date.parse(value);

                // it is a date
                if (isNaN(d)) { // d.valueOf() could also work
                    ngModel.$setValidity('valid', false);
                } else {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('valid', true);
                }
            }

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$viewValue;
            }, validate);
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="so">
    <input type="text" ng-model="date" is-date required/>
    <p ng-show="!so.$valid">Date is invalid!</p>
    <p ng-show="so.$valid">Date is valid!</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be in form element? Can I give that name='so' to the input type itself?

Comment: @user2507845 what datepicker are you using?

Comment: I wish to disable the date validator so client calendar implementations will still work with type=date